# Form validation with JavaScript using XHR

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, I've been using tutorials online but they seem to often validate with php and use JavaScript for warnings, the application I'm making users xhr to post the data to the server, but before this I want to have JavaScript complete some validations. Then I'll re validate with the PHP.

Here is the form code

```
<form id="booking" action="">
                <span class="red">*</span>First Name:
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
                <br>

                <span class="red">*</span>Last Name:
                <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
                <br>

                <span class="red">*</span>Contact Number:
                <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
                <br>

                Unit Number(optional):
                <input type="text" name="unit" id="unit">
                <br>

                <span class="red">*</span>Street Number:
                <input type="text" name="streetNumber" id="streetNumber">
                <br>

                <span class="red">*</span>Street Name:
                <input type="text" name="streetName" id="streetName">
                <br>

                <span class="red">*</span>Suburb:
                <input type="text" name="pickupSuburb" id="pickupSuburb">
                <br>

                Destination Suburb<span class="red">*</span>:
                <input type="text" name="destinationSuburb" id="destinationSuburb">
                <br>
                Pick-Up Date and Time<span class="red">*</span>:
                <input type="datetime-local" name="dateTime" id="dateTime">
                <br>

                <br>
                <input type="button" value="Submit"
                       onclick="getData('bookingprocess.php','message', firstName.value, lastName.value, number.value, unit.value, streetNumber.value, streetName.value, pickupSuburb.value, destinationSuburb.value, dateTime.value)"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">

            </form>

 <div id="message">
            </div>
```

I've created a div for the warning messages.

Here is the JavaScript

```
// file simpleajax.js
var xhr = createRequest();
function getData(dataSource, divID, firstName, lastName, number, unit, streetNumber, streetName, pickupSuburb, destinationSuburb, dateTime)  {
    if(xhr) {
        var place = document.getElementById(divID);
        var requestbody = "firstName="+encodeURIComponent(firstName)+"&lastName="+encodeURIComponent(lastName)+"&number="+encodeURIComponent(number)+"&unit="+encodeURIComponent(unit)+"&streetNumber="+encodeURIComponent(streetNumber)+"&streetName="+encodeURIComponent(streetName)+"&pickupSuburb="+encodeURIComponent(pickupSuburb)+"&destinationSuburb="+encodeURIComponent(destinationSuburb)+"&dateTime="+encodeURIComponent(dateTime);
        xhr.open("POST", dataSource, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            place.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            } // end if
        } // end anonymous call-back function
        xhr.send(requestbody);
    } // end if
} // end function getData()

function checkForm(booking) {

    var valid = true;

    if(firstName.value.length <= 0) {
        window.alert("Name is empty");
        booking.firstName.focus();
        return valid = false;
    }
}
```

Note there will be more validations, my question is how can I call the validations from the form, or directly from the XHR, which is the best practice? I understand the call to the XHR from the form could be considered bad practice as well as I've hard coded all the values?

Getting this to work has been quite troublesome, so apologies if its a little Hodge podge.

Answer (score 0):

Validating while the form is filled (when the cursor leaves a field) makes more sense since you can add some hints to user. Like, if a user enters an email, you check if it contains `@` and it doesn't, it's much more user-friendly to notify them that something's wrong with their email input (in contrast, they may send the form, you validate it then and tell them the form is not ok, but then they have to fill the form again, which is sort of frustrating).

Try

```
<input type="text" onblur="alert('out!');" />
```

This fires when the input loses focus. Now, you may wonder how to use functions defined elsewhere in such handling. That can be done, for instance, like this:

**JS:**

```
window.myHandler = function(input,event) { ... };
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" onblur="window.myHandler(input,event);" />
```

Note that in HTML `onblur` attribute `event` is a "pre-defined" variable that contains the Event object "instance", but for elder versions of IE, you should use

```
window.myHandler = function(input,event) {
    event = event || window.event; // elder IE store the Event object in window.event
    // input is your DOM element. You can use input.value to get the value
    // or this.classList to add some class which indicates (via CSS) that the input is wrong
    ... 
};
```

Comment: Hi YaK, thats what I would like, but how do I do that? I'm trying to keep the JavaScript out of the index file, but should I do it all from there?

Comment: @Jcode sorry for delay, I've expanded the answer so that it answers the "how to implement" part

Comment: @Jcode by the way, do you use jQuery? It is of much help in here, especially if you want to prevent submitting when validation is failed